# Skin tension problem with frame drum

Tags: drums

I own a frame drum with a rawhide skin tacked on. Recently the skin tension dropped quite significantly. I know this might be due to temperature or humidity.

Is there a way to tighten the skin without re-tacking the skin? Perhaps by wetting the skin?

Thanks

Comment: For those of us with more engineering knowledge than drum knowledge, could you post a  photo of your drum ?

Answer (score 2):

Wetting the skin will loosen it further.  The only thing you can do is dry it out, for instance over a woodstove- something I had to do at a concert once.  But eventually, the only solution is to re-tack it.  Drums you can tighten the heads of- with srews, strings, wedges, or whatever- are easier to keep in tension, but more expensive.